# Executar função a cada classe que encontrar

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, html

Estou criando um mural de imagens dentro de *thumbnails* ajustando-as automaticamente, onde eu uso o cálculo abaixo:

```
if($('.thumb img').width()<$('.thumb img').height()){//portrait

  $('.thumb img').css({
    maxWidth:'100%'
  });
  $('.thumb img').css({
    marginTop:-(($('.thumb img').height()-$('.thumb').height())/2)
  });
}else{//landscape
  $('.thumb img').css({
    maxHeight:'100%'
  });
  $('.thumb img').css({
    marginLeft:-(($('.thumb img').width()-$('.thumb').width())/2)
  });
}
```

Se eu tenho penas uma imagem, ele calcula bem, mas quando tenho imagens de tamanhos diferentes ele encontra um *bug*. Queria saber se há uma forma de eu executar essa função a cada vez que encontrar uma `div` com a class `.thumb`, pois assim posso tratar imagem por imagem e estruturar elas dentro das suas div's específicas.

Answer (score 5):

Para executar determinada função para cada elemento usa-se:

```
$('.thumb img').each(function(){
if($(this).width()<$(this).height()){//portrait

 $(this).css({
    maxWidth:'100%'
  });
  $(this).css({
    marginTop:-(($(this).height()-$('.thumb').height())/2)
  });
}else{//landscape
  $(this).css({
    maxHeight:'100%'
  });
  $(this).css({
    marginLeft:-(($(this).width()-$('.thumb').width())/2)
  });
}
});
```

Repare que dentro do metodo `each` todas as referencias a class `.thumb` e o elemento `img`, foram trocadas por `$(this)`, nesse caso o `this` aponta para o elemento que está sendo percorrido.

Comment: Faltou trocar as referências a `$('.thumb')`.

Comment: o $('.thumb') , nao vai ser this pois estou rodando o loop diretamente nos elementos do tipo img que tem essa classe, e não só na classe. mas poderia ser feito também só na classe. mas meu entendimento da questão dizia que era só nessa situação especifica, me corrija se estiver errado porfavor.

Comment: Maravilha, obrigado! tava começando a sentir cheiro de queimado aqui na sala rsrs... Valeu @Guerra

Comment: Sem problemas LeandroLUK, não se esqueça de marcar a resposta correta como "certa" para ajudar futuros usuários com a mesma dúvida.

Comment: Só precisa ver certinho esse $('.thumb') ai porque se tiver mais de 1 elemento ele vai retornar um array e você não vai conseguir pegar o width ou height como quer, como vai funcionar? vai ser um elemento modelo?

Comment: Se todos os `.thumb` tiverem as mesmas dimensões não haverá problema (`$('.thumb').width()` retorna a largura do primeiro elemento encontrado). Eu entendi que seria necessário pegar o container de cada imagem específica, por isso usei `$(this).closest('.thumb')` na minha resposta.

Comment: Realmente o @bfavaretto tem razão, tem que ver certinho qual $('.thumb') que você quer, para fazermos a captura correta

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa de um loop:

```
$('.thumb img').each(function(){
    var img = $(this);
    var proporcao = img.width() / img.height();

    // Retrato
    if(proporcao > 1) {
        img.css({
            maxWidth:'100%',
            marginTop:-((img.height()-img.closest('.thumb').height())/2)
        });

    // Paisagem
    } else {
        img.css({
            maxHeight:'100%',
            marginLeft:-((img.width()-img.closest('.thumb').width())/2)
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma função de jQuery para esse efeito é o [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) que permite executar um bloco de código por cada elemento localizado:

```
$('.thumb').each(function() {

   // o teu código aqui
});
```